# Python while loop not exiting correctly, 'Out of range' error seen on last iteration

Tags: python

I'll be honest and admit that I asked an earlier related question, but I have since found a solution to the earlier issue and am now hitting another issue!  I am iterating through a list to search a large text file.  The search involves taking the first list entry and using that string (of digits) it goes through the text file searching for that entry.  The script works ok up to the last iteration/last list entry, whereby I get the following error in cmd window...

```
2014 Apr 25  09:46:58.884  [35]  0x5245  FFFF Rec rst 4444 A

18.84
2014 Apr 25  09:46:58.902  [81]  0x5245  FFFF Rec rst 4444 A

19.62
2014 Apr 25  09:46:58.944  [2B]  0x5245  FFFF Rec rst 4444 A

16.69
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\MEAN_val.py", line 361, in <module>
duta()
File "C:\MEAN_val.py", line 120, in duta
for word in [framelist[num]]:
IndexError: list index out of range
Exception RuntimeError: RuntimeError('sys.meta_path must be a list of import hoo
ks',) in <bound method Workbook.__del__ of <xlsxwriter.workbook.Workbook object
at 0x0241F2F0>> ignored
```

It seems that the while num<=len(framelist): function isn't working and it is not exiting the loop once the num reaches the length of the list.

Here's my partially working code...

```
for root, subFolders, files in chain.from_iterable(os.walk(path) for path in paths):
        for filename in files:  
            if filename.endswith('.txt'): 

                with open(os.path.join(root, filename), 'r') as fBMA:

                    searchlinesBMA = fBMA.readlines()
                    fBMA.close()



                    num = 0


                    while num<=len(framelist):
                        for i, line in enumerate(searchlinesBMA):
                            for word in [framelist[num]]:
                                if word in line:
                                    keylineBMA = searchlinesBMA[i-2]
                                    Rline = searchlinesBMA[i+10]
                                    Rline = re.sub('[()]', '', Rline)
                                    valueR = Rline.split()
                                    split = keylineBMA.split()
                                    if split[10] == 'A':
                                        print keylineBMA
                                        print valueR[3]
                                        num+=1

                                    break
```

Thanks for reading,
MikG

Comment: Indices in arrays are 0-based, whereas `len` is a count, i.e. 1-based. Change it to `while num < len(framelist):`

Comment: Should be `while num < len(framelist):` Note LT rather than LTE

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't just do `for frame in framelist:` and avoid all that messing around with `num`? Also `for word in [framelist[num]]:` is a loop that completes exactly once so might as well be an assignment `word = framelist[num]` unless those outer `[]` are spurious.

Comment: Thanks all for your advice.  Unfortunately even after changing to while num < len(framelist):  I still get the same error.  Normally I would suspect the text file is incorrect, but this is not the case.  It still seems to go on one iteration too far.  Is there a way to cleanly exit when the error occurs?

Comment: or rather I now get this cmd error  if split[10] == 'A':
IndexError: list index out of range.  It still Seems to be similar case of one iteration too far

Comment: I decided to use except IndexError:, pass,continue to exit the loop on out of Index error.  The generated Excel seems to match up dispite this, so not sure where the original error was coming from.  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to cleanly exit the loop using the following code.  Written Excel matches up anyway, so still a bit unsure why the Index Error was there?

```
except IndexError:
    pass
continue
```

Answer (score 2):

You can change your code to:

```
while num<len(framelist)
```

because the length is simply a count. If you start at zero and go to (including) the length, you are going through the loop (length + 1) times